# What is the origin and meaning of the suffix -late, as in "isolate" and "desolate"?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

I am sure that the word *late* as in *tardy* does not have the same origin. It certainly does not correlate with the terms.

I wonder if the actual suffix is closer to "olate" given my aforementioned terms.

Comment: English has no such suffix as *-late*. If it had, you would have been able to find an entry for it in any dictionary.

Answer (score 12):

The suffix involved is '-ate', and it reached the English nouns (or adjectives) by two different routes. *OED* gives '-ate' in 'isolate' as

> **-ate**, *suffix*<sup>1</sup>
>
> ....
>
> 2. In some words, *-ate* = French *-ate*, < Latin or Italian *-āta*, as in *pirate*, *frigate*.

'Isolate' reached English from Italian *isolato* (and French *isolé*), themselves deriving from Latin *insulātus*.

For 'desolate' (noun and adjective), the route was more directly from Latin *dēsōlātus*, past participle of *dēsōlāre*.

The verbs 'isolate' and 'desolate' also differ significantly, etymologically speaking. 'Desolate' was formed on the model of the adjective, and first occurs much later than the adjective. 'Isolate' is a back-formation from the adjective **or** derives from French *isoler* (itself from Italian *isolare*, which is from Latin *insulāre*), plus the verb suffix '-ate'.

That's all very tortuous and, as you probably gathered from mention of 'pirate' and 'frigate', the bare meaning of the suffix is not especially germane to the conglomerative meaning of the terms. More germane is the meaning of the Latin stem that gave rise to 'isolate' and 'desolate', that is, *sol*, meaning "alone, only".

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that *insulare* comes from *solus* ("alone")? The traditional explanation is that it comes from *salum* ("sea"). Alternatively, the Online Etymology Dictionary cites an argument that it's actually "a loanword from an unknown language".

Comment: @ruakh, good observation, although the discussion seems well out of scope for this answer. Neither the "traditional explanation" nor the suggestion in etymonline are agreeable to me. My own reasoning, to a point, follows that of Nettleship in [On the Etymology of Consul, Exsul, Insula, Praesul](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uva.x004619542;view=1up;seq=286) (1872). I reject *in salo* and *in* and *sar-* (p 273, bottom). In brief, I embrace the *sol-* suggestion made (p 273, top) but not much explored by Nettleship.

Answer (score 10):

The suffix in words *desolate* and *isolate* is not *late* at all; it's *-ate(1)*  in adjective *desolate* and *-ate(2)* in verb *isolate* as explained in the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ate).

> **[-ate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ate)** (1): word-forming element used in forming nouns from Latin words ending in -atus, -atum (such as estate, primate, senate).
>   Those that came to English via Old and Middle French often arrived
>   with -at, but an -e was added after c. 1400 to indicate the long
>   vowel. The suffix also can mark adjectives formed from Latin past
>   participals in -atus, -ata (such as desolate, moderate, separate);
>   again, they often were adopted in Middle English as -at, with an -e
>   appended after c. 1400.
>
> **[-ate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ate)** (2): verbal suffix for Latin verbs in -are, identical with -ate (1). Old English commonly made verbs from adjectives by
>   adding a verbal ending to the word (such as gnornian "be sad, mourn,"
>   gnorn "sad, depressed"), but as the inflections wore off English words
>   in late Old and early Middle English, there came to be no difference
>   between the adjective and the verb in dry, empty, warm, etc. Thus
>   accustomed to the identity of adjectival and verbal forms of a word,
>   the English, when they began to expand their Latin-based vocabulary
>   after c. 1500, simply made verbs from Latin past-participial
>   adjectives without changing their form (such as aggravate,
>   substantiate) and it became the custom that Latin verbs were Englished
>   from their past participle stems.

**[isolate](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=isolate)** (v):

> "to set or place apart, to detach so as to make alone," by 1786, a
>   back-formation from **isolated** (q.v.).  As a noun, "something
>   isolated," 1890; from earlier adjectival use (1819), which is from
>   Italian ***isolato*** or Medieval Latin ***insulatus***.

**[isolated (adj):](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=isolate)**

> "standing detached from others of its kind," 1740, a rendering into
>   English of French ***isolé*** "isolated" (17c.), from Italian
>   ***isolato***, from Latin ***insulatus*** "made into an island," from ***insula*** "island". English at first used the French word (*isole*, also *isole'd*, c. 1750), then after isolate (v.) became an English
>   word, *isolated* became its past participle.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a *-late* suffix.  *Isolate* comes from *insulatus* ("made into an island") and *desolate* from *desolatus* ("abandoned").  The *-atus* ending is just the past-participle ending in Latin, equivalent to our *-ed*.

Comment: I had wondered because both these words have a lonely edge to them. Maybe -latus means something, as these two have similarities.

Comment: @AbiDanielleBegin No, they just happen to come from words that both have an l in their final root syllable. _-latus_ does mean something in Latin, as in _translatus_, _elatus_, _allatus_, etc.: it means ‘carried’. It is the past participle of _ferrō_ ‘bear, carry’. But that's not what it is in these two words; here the l is simply part of the derivational bases _insula_ of unknown origin and _sōlus_ ‘alone, sole, only’, probably based on the pronoun _se_ ‘(one)self’, but of unknown derivation.

Comment: Latin *ferro* is a wildly irregular verb (principal parts *ferro, ferre, tuli, latum*) - which might suggest it is really a merger of two or even three different verbs.

Comment: @alephzero -- I read that _went_ was originally the past tense of _wend_, but somehow _go_ picked it up and _wend_ had to content itself with the regular form _wended_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Should just be one *r* in *ferō*. The inflections with two are based on the infinitive not the normal stem.

Comment: @tchrist Oops, typo! _Ferō_, of course.

Comment: @alephzero Just two stems. The forms in _fer-_ are from PIE _*bʰer-_ (as _bear_ in English), while the perfect _tulī_ and the past participle _lātum_ are both from _*telh₂-_ ‘lift, bear, carry’. _Tulī_ is simplified from an earlier, reduplicated _tetulī_ (< _*te-tolh₂-_), while _lātum_ is from _*tlātum_ (< _*tlh₂-tó-). The original present of _*telh₂-_ was a nasal present, which became its own separate verb in Italic, in Latin [_tollō_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tollo#Latin) ‘raise, lift, elevate’, which got an extra _sub-_ prefixed to distinguish it from the other one.